# Extracting unique syscall names from strace output (via regex?)

Tags: python, c, regex, linux, notepad++

I have a file produced by [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) which contains all the system calls. Now I want to get the name of all system calls. Therefore, say if I have `mprotect` listed 4 times, I only need to list it 1 time, that is I only need to list unique system calls.

One method that comes to mind is to use regular expressions using python or any other language that supports parsing regular expression to first see all system calls and then eliminate the duplicates. For that purpose, I was first trying to test my regular expression using the search feature of notepad++. I want to match anything like this, `blah(`. For that purpose I devised the following regular expression

`[a-zA-Z_](`

but notepad found nothing. What do you think is the correct regular expression for this?

Comment: I think you're just looking for the `-c` option to strace...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you think you need regular expressions for this? The output of `strace` is a sequence of lines, each starting with

```
<c_identifier>(
```

and C identifiers can't contain `(`, so you can just take the part up to the `(` to get the name of the system calls. In Python, this one-liner computes the set of distinct system calls:

```
syscalls = set(ln.split('(', 1)[0] for ln in strace_output)
```

(You can do this in one line of Awk as well, if you rather work in the shell than in Python.)

Comment: Don't you want a `[0]` after the `split()` call?

Comment: Not every system call is on separate line, some system calls occupy more than 1 line, such as clone, which has a long list of parameters.

Comment: @user1018562 actually -- even if it wraps in the editor, there shouldn't be a newline in strace's literal output, so this solution should work correctly.

Comment: @user1018562: not so; that's just your terminal window or editor wrapping long lines.

Comment: Actually, the strace lines don't necessarily start with "<c_identifier>(". Depending on the strace options used, "<c_identifier>(" may be prefixed by <process_ID>, some spaces, <time>, a space, [<instruction_pointer>], a space.  <process_ID> is an unsigned integer, <time> is a floating value, and <instruction_pointer> is a (32-bit) hexadecimal integer.

"<c_identifier>(" may further be prefixed by "<... " in the case of resumed system calls.

Further, any signals will insert lines that replace "<c_identifier>(" with something beginning with "--- " or "+++ ".

Answer (score 5):

Notepad++ should have told you **invalid regular expression**. The latest version does.

In regular expressions, parentheses have special meaning, so you have to escape them:

```
[a-zA-Z_]\(
```

will find `h(` in `blah(`, since the part in the brackets isn't quantified (as @CharlesDuffy pointed out).

To match the entire `blah(`, use

```
[a-zA-Z_]+\(
```

Comment: You need a `+` or `*` after the group for it to match multiple characters; as given it matches only one.

Comment: Technically, it will match `h(` - which is a subset of `blah(`. It works, but it would match just as well for `jkhsf*&*&@#@#h(`. Perhaps `^[a-zA-Z_]+\(` would be appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

It should be `[a-zA-Z_]+\(` instead. This is because round brackets are used as meta characters.